Systemd service does not start automatically at boot, service is enabled
I’m facing an issue with a systemd service I created on an Ubuntu 20.04.6 system running on an ARM64 platform. The service is supposed to execute a simple Bash script at boot, but it does not start automatically. I tested variuos services with the same result, this is just a sample one. Here are the details:
Script (/home/username/test.sh):
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script started at $(date)" >> /home/username/test_service.log

Service File (/etc/systemd/system/test_service.service):
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/username/test.sh
Restart=no
Type=oneshot
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=test_service
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Current Status:

The script works correctly when executed manually:
sh /home/username/test.sh

It writes the expected output to /home/username/test_service.log.

The service starts correctly when triggered manually and I can see a line added to the log:
sudo systemctl start test_service.service


The service is enabled for startup:
sudo systemctl is-enabled test_service.service

Output:
enabled


No logs are recorded for this service after boot:
sudo journalctl -u test_service.service -b

Output:
-- No entries --


No errors and logs in journalctl
username@hostname:~$ sudo journalctl -b | grep test_service
Nov 22 09:38:28 hostname sudo[2264]:     username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -u test_service.service -b
username@hostname:~$ sudo systemctl start test_service.service
username@hostname:~$ sudo journalctl -b | grep test_service
Nov 22 09:38:28 hostname sudo[2264]:     username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -u test_service.service -b
Nov 22 09:39:19 hostname sudo[2271]:     username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start test_service.service
Nov 22 09:39:19 hostname systemd[1]: test_service.service: 
Succeeded.


systemctl status test_service.service:
systemctl status test_service.service

test_service.service - Test Service
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)





What I've Tried:

Verified the script is executable and has the correct permissions (chmod +x /home/username/test.sh).
Reloaded the systemd configuration with sudo systemctl daemon-reload.
Re-enabled the service with sudo systemctl enable test_service.service.
Checked for errors using sudo systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/test_service.service—no errors were reported.

Questions:

Why doesn’t the service start automatically at boot, even though it is enabled and works fine manually?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Add the output of systemctl status test_service.service. Maybe the service starts before /home/username/test_service.log is available. I would remove all entries with syslog remove the redirection to the log file.

thank you, systemctl status test_service.service added in main post:Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) tried removig syslog entries, same result.

Observations; You are running manually with sh /home/username/test.sh but have a shebang of #!/bin/bash. Probably not the issue but isn’t consistent. You have ExecStart=/home/username/test.sh but I find I have used ExecStart= usr/bin/sh /home/username/test.sh in my unit files. You could also try running as your own user and a type of simple. Your service will be inactive (dead) almost immediately. Try adding a `sleep 300’ or similar to keep it alive for long enough to see it’s alive

This works as expected:
The unit file
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/test_service.service 
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=bash -c 'echo "Script started at $(date)"'
Restart=no
Type=oneshot
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The service status
$ systemctl status test_service.service
● test_service.service - Test Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2024-11-25 09:10:13 CET; 1min 55s ago
    Process: 1508 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c echo "Script started at $(date)" (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
   Main PID: 1508 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost systemd[1]: Starting Test Service...
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost bash[1508]: Script started at Mo 25 Nov 2024 09:10:13 CET
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost systemd[1]: test_service.service: Succeeded.
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost systemd[1]: Finished Test Service.

The log output
$ journalctl -b 0 -xefu test_service.service
-- Logs begin at Mon 2024-06-24 07:53:06 CEST. --
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost systemd[1]: Starting Test Service...
-- Subject: A start job for unit test_service.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit test_service.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 225.
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost bash[1508]: Script started at Mo 25 Nov 2024 09:10:13 CET
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost systemd[1]: test_service.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit test_service.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Nov 25 09:10:13 myhost systemd[1]: Finished Test Service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit test_service.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit test_service.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 225.


Unfortunately it does not work on my setup, so there should be some issue in the systemctl itself. Copied and pasted your service but I got no logs with: journalctl -b 0 -xefu test_service.service. I need to inspect deeper into systemctl, since I just flashed the board from scratch and I got the same issue.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 bot no ARM64 platform. Is your network.target active?
